# Single Ionic app for web and mobile or two separate Ionic and Angular apps?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to start with a mobile and desktop friendly web client. Eventually, I would also like to build native mobile (Android/iOS) versions.

I have lots of experience with old AngularJS, and moderate experience with the newer Ionic and Angular frameworks. But haven't made a web app with them.

My options seem to be:

1. Go with a single Ionic 3 project, and make it deploy for web and native apps, having env-specific CSS and features all in one codebase.
2. Start with Angular 6 for web and later create a sibling codebase in Ionic that pulls in some of the Angular code (or break it out into a shared lib).
3. Another option?

Any suggestions? Warnings? Example templates or reading to follow?

Comment: You will get opinionated answers of any. The answer depends on what you are building and you limit context by saying web client...

Answer (score 0):

I would wait until Ionic 4.  They are working to put the mobile as a project into the workspace, so you can have a desktop, mobile and shared libraries between the two all in a single angular workspace.

Comment: That sounds great! Not sure I can wait, but good to know. Any links to more info on this? I looked but couldn't find info about this on any of the future-Ionic-4-features blog posts I found.